# element is not attached to the page document (selenium python)

Tags: python, html, selenium, web-scraping, webdriver

I've been trying to log in to my broker account to make some automated requests to buying and selling as it has no API.
[here is the link to my broker site.](https://groww.in/login)

I tried using Explicit Waits in selenium but it didn't work. After a lot of trials, I got to know that the js is working to create the new HTML element which is not been updated to selenium so it's unable to find the element.

[Here is the image before I enter my mail](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qQetr.jpg) 
And it's HTML :

```
<input class="" id="login_email1" type="text" maxlength="250" min="0" max="10000000" autocomplete="on" placeholder="" required="" style="font-size: 15px;">
```

[Here is the image after I enter my mail](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2uf3f.jpg)
And it's HTML:

```
<input class="" id="login_email2" type="text" maxlength="250" min="0" max="10000000" autocomplete="on" placeholder="" required="" style="font-size: 15px;">
<input class="" id="login_password1" type="password" maxlength="250" min="0" max="10000000" autocomplete="on" placeholder="" required="" style="font-size: 15px;">
```

Here even the mail input ID is also changed and the password element is been added so selenium is unable to find that element. Can I get a solution or any alternative for this issue?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You are right, after inserting your email address OTP is sent and you are transferred to the next page so the email input element there is different. But why is it bothering you? Now you have to open your email, preferable in some other tab, get the OTP and put it here to continue.

Comment: No otp is sent for existing accounts we just have to use our mail and password if account exists. That's how i normally login to my account

Comment: OK, I do not have account there so I can't see the steps for redistricted user

Comment: I have uploaded the images and the gave the html code of elements.

Comment: i can't see the elements properties from your pictures so this absolutely doesn't help